# iPhone 6 battery drain fast

Tags: iphone, battery

My mom's iPhone battery is suddenly draining very fast (its losing 1% in a 10 second time period when the screen is on), so I checked the battery health in the Settings app, and it says it has 51% maximum capacity. We are going to replace he battery regardless! But even if the battery is very bad i don’t think it’s supposed to drain this fast. My question: what can I do right now to stop it from draining so quick while I look for replacement options?

Comment: What's the question here? You're already doing what you need to do, replace the battery.

Comment: What makes you believe a battery in need of replacing "isn't supposed to drain so fast."  If battery cell(s) don't hold a charge anymore, it will "drain fast" after charging.

Comment: Probably time to replace the battery, as others have said. iOS 11.4 also has received [many reports](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8409995) of draining battery. Make sure you're on the latest iOS 11.4.1 to help alleviate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once they start to go, they go fast.
Mine went from 'perfectly fine all day' to 'need to carry a charger with you' in about a month.

[image]

Switch it into Low Power mode for now, ring Apple & arrange to take it to an Apple Store or for them to collect it.
Battery change takes 2 hours if you take it in or 3 days by post. [They say it can take longer but that's direct experience.]

Do it soon because the low price battery replacement offer ends in September, so I've heard.

You must release it from Find my iPhone before they will accept it.
Safest is to fully back it up & erase it before handing it over.
If you have a spare iPhone, restore it from that backup & drop the SIM into it for the duration.